# Convert from JSON into HTML table with format like this

Tags: php, jquery, json, html

I have an object deserialised from JSON like this:

```js
{
  "Wilayah": "BALI ",
  "Jns_Brg": "WATER DISPANSER ",
  "Kd_Brg": "WDP-300 ",
  "Kd_Trn": "J",
  "Qty": "159",
  "Bulan": 7,
  "Tahun": 2017
}, {
  "Wilayah": "BANDUNG ",
  "Jns_Brg": "WATER DISPANSER",
  "Kd_Brg": "WDP-300 ",
  "Kd_Trn": "J",
  "Qty": "2522",
  "Bulan": 7,
  "Tahun": 2017
}, {
  "Wilayah": "BANDUNG ",
  "Jns_Brg": "BLENDER ",
  "Kd_Brg": "BL-101 ",
  "Kd_Trn": "J",
  "Qty": "4554",
  "Bulan": 7,
  "Tahun": 2017
}
```

I want to display the data in the table like this.

```
Kd_Brg | Bali | Bandung
       | 7    |  7
========================
WDP-300| 159  | 2522
BL-101 |      | 4554
```

How can I approach this ? backend php , frontend bootstrap jquery + html

Comment: Check out this [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/jongha/jquery-jsontotable).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $json= "your json code";
    $data =  json_decode($json);
    if (count($data->stand)){
        // Open the table
        echo "<table>";

        // Cycle through the array
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

            // Output a row
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$key."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        // Close the table
        echo "</table>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: This would be where I would start too for a basic table.  It puts the rendering on the server and not your browser (via JS or jquery) and so will load your page faster.